# Querying for Bounding Box in PostGIS Yields Unintended Result Set

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I create the data set of 1'000'000 uniformly random points in [0,1]x[0,1] with R and then export it as a CSV so I can load it into Postgres/PostGIS.

R:

```
N <- 1000000
df <- data.frame(id=1:N, lon=runif(N), lat=runif(N))
write.table(df,"/media/Volume/temp/random_points.csv",row.names=FALSE,sep=";")
# manually remove header from CSV

head(df)
#  id       lat       lon
#1  1 0.9094180 0.1208861
#2  2 0.8009161 0.8499304
#3  3 0.9800282 0.3757218
#4  4 0.5795991 0.4551454
#5  5 0.8988043 0.7801994
#6  6 0.9456310 0.2343178
```

PostGIS:

```
create table random_points (id serial, lat float, lon float);
ALTER TABLE random_points ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

# now I import CSV into table

ALTER TABLE random_points ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINT,4326);

UPDATE random_points SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326);

CREATE INDEX idx_lon_lat ON random_points USING GIST(geom);
```

And now I would like to query for all points lying within the bounding box - powered by an index:

min lat = 0.342, max lat = 0.352, min lon = 0.793, max lon = 0.812

```
SELECT *
FROM random_points
WHERE random_points.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(0.342, 0.352, 0.793, 0.812, 4326);
```

But not only do I get a result set of size 207'376 which is much more than what I get with R (177) - the expected value for the area would be 190.

Already the first record does not belong to the intended bounding box; even if I confused longitude and latitude somewhere:

```
4;0.579599140677601;0.45514538907446;"...138CE23F"
9;0.618269162718207;0.392739744856954;"...9DCC8E33F"
10;0.742938967887312;0.58326911740005;"...127C6E73F"
17;0.665668761124834;0.475526283029467;"...92284DE53F"
27;0.668456399813294;0.747356393141672;"...ACFE63E53F"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

My intention is to benchmark querying points with a bounding box in PostGIS to evaluate when it makes sense to use PostGIS for that purpose from R as opposed to using data frame/table tools.

Comment: You might be interested in PL/R, stored procedures in R within Postgres: http://www.joeconway.com/plr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `ST_MakeEnvelope` are in the order xmim, ymin, xmax, ymax. You're passing ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax.

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html